# Cannot link gtest_main as external static library with cmake and Cygwin. i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main

Tags: cmake, static, cygwin, googletest, static-linking

I am looking for a way to compile google test as a static library and link this library to my projects.
I need this to speedup the unit testing. And need to avoid downloading by using "FetchContent_"
I am working on windows with Cygwin. Is it correct to have google test compiled as an external static library?

But I have experienced a problem with linking google test as a static library to my unit test.

There is my CMake script:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
set(LIBPREFIX "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}")
set(LIBSUFFIX "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
set(GTEST_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../testSuite/googletest/build/lib")
set(GTEST_INCLUDES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../testSuite/googletest/include")
set(GTEST_LIBRARY  "${GTEST_LOCATION}/${LIBPREFIX}gtest${LIBSUFFIX}")
set(GTEST_MAINLIB  "${GTEST_LOCATION}/${LIBPREFIX}gtest_main${LIBSUFFIX}")

add_library(GTest IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(GTest PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION                 "${GTEST_LIBRARY}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES     "${GTEST_INCLUDES}"
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")

add_library(GTestMain IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(GTestMain PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${GTEST_MAINLIB}"
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES
        "${GTEST_LIBRARY};${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")
        
        
...

target_link_libraries(test_${ModuleName} PRIVATE ${ModuleName}_lib GTest GTestMain fff_if)
...
```

I constantly recevied error:

**/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main**

Could you please advise the best way to link google test as static by using Cmake and use preexisted google test static library!

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**
Needed libraries are here:
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../testSuite/googletest/build/lib/

Also I was able to resolve the issue by using find_library():

```
find_library(
    LIBGTESTMAIN_LIBRARY
    NAMES gtest_main
    HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../testSuite/googletest/build/lib/)
find_library(
    LIBGTEST_LIBRARY
    NAMES gtest
    HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../testSuite/googletest/build/lib/)

message(STATUS "LIBGTESTMAIN_LIBRARY=${LIBGTESTMAIN_LIBRARY}")
message(STATUS "LIBGTEST_LIBRARY=${LIBGTEST_LIBRARY}")

...
target_link_libraries(test_${ModuleName} PRIVATE ${ModuleName}_lib  timer_lib ${LIBGTEST_LIBRARY} ${LIBGTESTMAIN_LIBRARY} fff_if)
...
```

Comment: where is `libgtest_main*.a` ?

Comment: Needed libraries are here: 
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../testSuite/googletest/build/lib/